# Android studio error avd (Прекращена работа программы "adb.exe")

Tags: android, avd

При нажатии на "Run" окно с поиском девайсов ничего не находит и вылетает ошибка (Прекращена работа программы "adb.exe"). Не работает ни с телефоном, ни с генимоушином, ни со стандартным AVD.
Обновы и SDK что я только с ними уже ни делал... 
Как исправить плиз подскажите...

Answer (score 1):

Я исправил эту ошибку: удалил из SDK обновленную папку `platform-tools` и вставил на её место предыдущую версию.

Comment: А почему обновленная версия хуже чем старая?